# Unable to get all token elements using StringTokenizer

Tags: java

I am tryting to split string by "," using StringTokenizer but not able to get whole values , token count shows 3 but printing only two elements, i have added my code below
if i have tried with two other inputs
**"Ravi,Tuti,786" - same output
"Ravi,Tuti,786,pincode"  getting three tokens not last one**

```
public class Tokenizer{
public static void main(String[] args){
String str = "Ravi,Tuti,786";//survival of fittest,journey to get job,update skill,try,get job";
        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(str,",");
        System.out.println(stk.countTokens());
        for(int i=0;i<=stk.countTokens();i++){
        System.out.println(stk.nextToken());}
}
}
```

output is

```
3
Ravi
Tuti
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasMoreTokens()` with `nextToken`:

```
public class Tokenizer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "Ravi,Tuti,786";//survival of fittest,journey to get job,update skill,try,get job";
     StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(str,",");
     System.out.println(stk.countTokens());

     while (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
     }

   }
}
```

---

The problem with your approach is that you are running `countTokens` in the `for` loop, which changes after `nextToken` is called.

If you want to use a `for` loop, you need to save the token count to a variable:

```
int numTokens = stk.countTokens();
for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++) {
  System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: hi yes it is working fine but would you please let me know what i did wrong for loop also looping till it gets three tokens right...?

Comment: See my updated answer about saving the token count to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `hasTokens()` method.

```
for( ; stk.hasMoreTokens() ; ) {
    System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time and letting me to learn new things snr bro

Answer (score 1):

The `countTokens()` method returns:

> the number of tokens remaining in the string using the current delimiter set.

So in your `if` loop it keeps getting evaluating and returning smaller numbers. To prevent this you can resolve it to a variable

```
int length = stk.countTokens();
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
}
```

If you do not wish to introduce another variable you can start `i` at what `countTokens()` returns and then loop until `i` is more that zero (While subtracting from `i` instead of adding)

```
for(int i=stk.countTokens();i>0;i--){
    System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
Ravi
Tuti
786
```